# whats wrong with my method for searching a non-binary tree (n-ary tree)?

Tags: java, search

hi i have this code to search a n-ary tree but it dosent works correctly and i dont know whats wrong with that
when searching n4 and n5 it return n3
whats wrong?
[image]

```
public FamilyNode findNodeByName(FamilyNode nodeName ){
       if(this.name.equals(nodeName.name)){
          // We found a node named nodeName, return it
          return this;
       } 
       // That's not me that you are looking for, let's see my kids

           for(FamilyNode child : this.children){
            if(child.findNodeByName(nodeName) != null) 
              return child;
                // We found what we are looking, just return from here
            //    return child;

       }
       // Finished looping over all nodes and did not find any, return null
       return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you give back the node in which a node was found. Once a node is found, this node needs to be returned, and the parent nodes in case a `FamilyNode` was found needs to return the found `FamilyNode`. Check what is done with the `found` variable.

You need to do something like this:

```
FamilyNode found = child.findNodeByName(nodeName);
if(found != null) 
    return found;
```

The entire method will look like:

```
public FamilyNode findNodeByName(FamilyNode nodeName ){
    if(this.name.equals(nodeName.name)){
        return this;
    } 
    for(FamilyNode child : this.children){
        FamilyNode found = child.findNodeByName(nodeName);
        if(found != null) 
            return found;
    }
    return null;
}
```